# Getting the number of fingers touching a UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uitouch

I want to change the color of a UIView based on the number of touches currently on it. I have managed to create this with a single touch:

```
class colorChangerViewClass: UIView {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        setColor(color: .blue)
        print("touchesBegan")
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        setColor(color: .green)
        print("touchesEnded")
    }


    func setColor(color: UIColor) {
    self.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```

But I am struggling with implementing multitouch. I feel like I'm not understanding something here.

**Does UIView have a property to check how many fingers are currently touching it?**

I could check that each time a new touchesBegan or touchesEnded occurs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First enable multi touch on your subclass

```
self.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
```

Then inside your touch event functions you can get all touches with event from your UIView class.

```
let touchCount = event?.touches(for: self)?.count
```

Comment: `event?.touches(for: self)?.count` may not always working, `event?.allTouches?.count` can also be helpful in `touchesBegan` method.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `UIView` has `isMultipleTouchEnabled = true`, the default is `false`.

Then change the `touchesBegan` method

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        setColor(color: .blue)
        let touchCount = event?.touches(for: self)?.count
    }
```